# Can I short circuit the SSR load terminals?

Tags: solid-state-relay, short-circuit

I'm using an SSR but I would also like to be able to turn on the circuit using a switch. Can I use a switch in parallel with the SSR load outputs? This would cause a short between the terminals.

The following diagram illustrates the idea. If the SSR actually works as switch this would be ok, but I want to make sure, considering its true behavior.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiZiKJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sure you can, I would like to inform you that SSR when gots damaged it usually remain in conductive mode. If the purpose is to have manual backup switch.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I got what you're saying. If I was to use it as a backup switch I should place it in series with the SSR. My purpose though is only to have it as an alternative, in case people want to turn on the circuit without using the micro controller. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And that was also my thought, wit an relay and alternating switch you can turn on/off both with contrller and manual. I will post an answer.

Comment: You could connect that "manual" switch to the microcontroller as well. This way you can fully program the behavior of this switch in combination with whatever logic is on your microcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

I've been doing this for years.

Answer (score 0):

How to turn on/off in both auto an manual mode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj6smH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relay could be bistable with two coils that swap the position of contact.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, once the switch is closed, the SSR output  is turned off, then  all current will flow through the switch.

Comment: The switch will have a near zero volt-drop. The triac will be about a volt. The current will flow through the switch whether the SSR is on or off.

Comment: After OP edit. This still isn't quite right. Depending on the SSR triggering arrangement the SSR could still be turned on but not conducting because the switch has lower resistance. If the switch is opened mid cycle the SSR would conduct in this case.